# web2py - trouble building a query

Tags: sql, web2py

I am having troubles building a query that does the following:

**Vehicle**
* make
* model
* trim
* part_number
* accuracy

First I do a query that finds the highest level of accuracy for each part number. I create a dictionary such that dic[part_number] = highest accuracy for this part_number

Then I want to do a second query. I match up make, model, and trim so some values. What I want to do next is check to see if the current record's accuracy is equal to the highest known accuracy level. Basically I only want records with the highest level of accuracy (that matches to the make, model, trim obviously)

What I've tried:
query &= (db.vehicle.accuracy == dict[db.vehicle.part_number])

I get the following error:
type 'exceptions.KeyError' gluon.dal.Field object at 0xsomeval

Is this the best way to approach this problem? Perhaps there is another way to get the result I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things worth noting there. First of all, to keep things neat, you may want to build a list of queries, and then reduce them using a function like the following:

```
def reduce_query_list(query_list, operator = 'and'):
    if operator == 'or':
        return reduce(lambda q01, q02:q01|q02, query_list) 
    elif operator == 'and':
        return reduce(lambda q01, q02:q01&q02, query_list)
```

Second, it looks like in the code above, you're trying to use an actual db field as a key, rather than using some value that's stored in a table in that field (which may account for that Exception). Are you sure that this is what you want to do?

EDIT:

If I understood correctly, your error comes from attempting to use Field objects as keys. Try to use the following as your list of keys instead:

```
part_number_list = [value['part_number'] for value in db(db.vehicle).select()]
```

Comment: I want the key to be the value of the part number for the record being considered. For example, I want to check, for each record, that if it's accuracy is the highest, then do not remove record from the result set. The dictionary stores the highest accuracy for each part number.

Comment: Right - it appears that what you're doing above is using the actual Field object (rather than any value in that field) from the DB table as your key. Instead, what you would want to use as a key is an actual value stored in that field. I'll edit the post above to see if I can show what I think you're trying to do could be done.